# Mixing DS with D1_V2 VM's in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, web-hosting, azure-virtual-machine

I'm designing an Azure solution for a webapplication that requires 2 VM's, a web-tier and an database-tier.

The web-tier contains the webapp that is a relatively large amount of calculation-work. The database-tier is a normal SQL server instance (+- 100 databases, total 500GB).

Azure offers the DS-series and D1_V2 series, the DS series supports SSD drives, the D1_V2 doesn't but has a 35% CPU than the DS.

Is my reasoning solid in thinking that I will be better off combining the 2 series, using the DS for the database-tier (SSD will provide higher IOPS for the database), while the D1_V2 will offer faster processing for my calculation-heavy webapp.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine those, because these are two completely different/standalone VMs.

It also makes sense that you use the V2 for your web server (due to its calculations) and a DS-series for you database server.

You should also use the Local SSD of you SQL Server machine to boost performance, e.g. by moving the temp db to it and/or setting up [Buffer Pool Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133176.aspx) and target the local SSD.

Comment: The majority of web servers will become IO bound well before they become CPU bound (unless it is insanely badly designed / written) I don't see any benefit in deploying any D class machines as web servers, they're just too expensive.

Comment: In General, I agree. But it was stated, that the web app is doing a lot of calculations.

Comment: @MichaelB you bring up a good point, it's hard to quantify the calculation-level though so it's even harder to see which bottleneck comes first, io or cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is solid and that may very well be the best way to deploy your solution.

However your methodology is perhaps rather flawed. What you say makes perfect sense, but you will never know whether that has any basis in reality until you test your application and see where the bottle necks are.

Considering how easy it is to scale a VM up or down, it doesn't take much to deploy and monitor and adjust accordingly.

In principal what you suggest is fine but reality crushes many a good principle.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but the big issue is, is that I can only resize the VM within its own vm-series. So if I choose a DS-vm, I can change to bigger/smaller DS vm's, but I can't change (easily) to D1_V2...

Comment: You would need a small script to detach the disk and create a new VM to switch series. You could start on the smaller series and if you found you are hitting performance limits look at the graphs and change the one that looks like its doing the most work.